# Update SQL records with other 2 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I would like to find a way to update a table with other 2 ones. 
Here is the scenario:

```
EmptyTbl: contents missing info (fname, lname, address)

Info1Tbl & Info2Tbl: complete info
```

Please see SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8b13/1 for the above table created.

Base on phone number and need to update `EmptyTbl` from `Info1Tbl` & `Info2Tbl` with Latest update info from these 2 tables. Please help with the query.

Comment: I've looked at your sqlFiddle and I'm still not clear on what you are trying to do.  How are the rows in EmptyTbl related to Info1Tbl and Info2Tbl?

Comment: @BillGregg by the phone field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
  select * from info1tbl
  union all
  select * from info2tbl
), cte2 as
(
  select *, row_number() 
  over (partition by phone order by lastupdated desc) rn
  from cte
)
--select * from cte2 where rn = 1
update e
set e.fname = cte2.fname, 
e.lname = cte2.lname, 
e.address = cte2.address
from emptytbl e
inner join cte2 on e.phone = cte2.phone
where rn = 1
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad761/1)

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following `UPDATE`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Info1Tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Info2Tbl
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY lastupdated DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
UPDATE A
SET A.fname = B.fname,
    A.lname = B.lname, 
    A.address = B.address
FROM EmptyTbl A
INNER JOIN CTE2 B
    ON A.phone = B.phone
WHERE B.RN = 1;

SELECT *
FROM EmptyTbl
```

The results:

```
╔════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════════════╦════════════╗
║ CUSTID ║  FNAME  ║ LNAME ║    ADDRESS     ║   PHONE    ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║    001 ║ Tom     ║ Suma  ║ 999 ABC Street ║ 1234567890 ║
║    002 ║ Naomy   ║ Bath  ║ 46 Main Street ║ 1234567891 ║
║    003 ║ Vanny   ║ Smith ║ 1234 Road      ║ 1234567892 ║
║    008 ║ Beth    ║ Tan   ║ 456 Ave.       ║ 1234567893 ║
║    005 ║ Richard ║ Howie ║ 45 Main Road   ║ 1234567894 ║
╚════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════════════╩════════════╝
```

And the [**modified sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8b13/8).